# Python: how to find right combination between two pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` contains the information of the link between an `ID` and a `Code`

```
df1
     ID   Code
0    48    3
1    47    2
2    50    0
3    49    1
```

`df2` contains the information of: the `ID` as index, some distances `d` and the different codes.

```
df2
       d1    d2 ... d100  Code1  Code2  ... Code100
47    3.2   5.4     45.2    3       2         1
48    1.4   7.4     46.7    0       3         2
49    5.4   8.9     33.2    1       2         0
50    6.3   8.7     47.5    3       0         2
```

I would like to associate to `df1` the distance relative to the same combination such as

```
df1
     ID   Code   d
0    48    3    7.4
1    47    2    5.4
2    50    0    8.7
3    49    1    5.4
```

Let me say that I have hundreds of Codes and Distances in `df2`.

The goal is to find the combinations of `df1` in `df2`. For instance the combination `ID=48` and `Code=3` is in the second row of `df2` with a distance `d2=7.4`

Comment: can you explain the rules?

Comment: The rule is to find the combinations of `df1` in `df2`. For instance the combination `ID=48` and `Code=3` is in the second row of `df2` with a distance `d2=7.4`

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'ID', right_on = df2.index)`?

Comment: @HS-nebula I need a merge also on the codes

Comment: Which `Code` in `df2` takes precedence?

Comment: Do the 1 and 2 in the `Code` and `d` columns match up to each other?

Comment: I have to find the `Code_x` that is equal to the `Code` in `df1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform merge with selective columns from the referenced `df2`. After that, you can concat the merged results.

```
m1 = df1.merge(df2.reset_index(), left_on=['ID', 'Code'], right_on=['index', 'Code1'])[['ID', 'Code', 'd1']].rename(columns={'d1': 'd'})
m2 = df1.merge(df2.reset_index(), left_on=['ID', 'Code'], right_on=['index', 'Code2'])[['ID', 'Code', 'd2']].rename(columns={'d2': 'd'})
res = pd.concat([m1, m2])
```

Output:

```
    ID  Code    d
0   49  1      5.4
0   48  3      7.4
1   47  2      5.4
2   50  0      8.7
```

Comment: the problem is that I have hundreds of `Code_x` and `d_x` in `df2`

Comment: This code would still work as it selects `Code1` and `Code2`, along with the `index.` @emax

Comment: but I would like to check all the `Code_x`

Comment: What do you mean? I suggest you come with a better [mcve] then. :)

Comment: `df2` can have 200 columns

Comment: Do you have d100 as well? every code is tied to d... codeN to dN... how come do you have just d1 and d2. What if code 13 is a match? which one do you choose? @emax

Comment: I have `d1`, `d2`, `d2`,....`d100` as well and there are not matches between codes